# When is a sum of products of positive powers of 2 and 3 divisible by $2^b-3^n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Here we have a really tough exercise.

Find all natural solution:

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n 2^{a_k} 3^{n-k}}{c}+3^n=2^{b} ,\quad 
b\geq a_n; \quad a_k, b, c ,n\in \mathbb N $$

Any ideas, hints?

Comment: Does $a(n)$ mean $a\cdot n$?

Comment: there is no further details for a(k)

Comment: If $a(k)$ is a sequence, I recommended you to write $a_k$(a_k) instead of $a(k)$..

Comment: i think a(k) jut depends on k. for example a(k)=k^2

Comment: so if a(k) is a sequence there is no chance to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

$$2^a3^{n-1}+2^{2a}3^{n-2}+\cdots+2^{an}3^0=c(2^b-3^n)$$
$$3^n\left(\left(\frac{2^a}3\right)^1+\left(\frac{2^a}3\right)^2+\left(\frac{2^a}3\right)^3+\cdots+\left(\frac{2^a}3\right)^n\right)=c(2^b-3^n)$$
$$3^n\left(\frac{\frac{2^a}3((2^a/3)^n-1)}{2^a/3-1}\right)=c(2^b-3^n)$$
$$2^a\left(\frac{2^a-3^n}{2^a-3}\right)=c(2^b-3^n)$$
$$2^a(2^a-3^n)=c(2^a-3)(2^b-3^n)$$
I hope you can solve now.

Comment: thanks for ur help but 900 sit-ups a day is right